# How to clear cells in Excel by macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying do a macro in excel that clear cells for A1:A100 but I have only find a macro that can do that to one cell. How can I make it work for more cells?

```
Sub ClearCell()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    If Rng.Cells(i,1) = "" Then
       Rng.Cells(i,1).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Google the usage of *used range*. Or try something like `Rng.Cells("A1:A100").ClearContents`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim Cl As Range
For Each Cl In [A1:A100]
    If Cl.Value = "" Then
        With Cl
            .ClearFormats
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End If
Next Cl
End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly you need? you want to remove cell format also or you just want to clear cell content?

Comment: post has been updated with `.ClearFormats`, is this what you asking for?

Comment: Thanks Vasily! I got it to work now. Many thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

better yet, try this:

```
Sub foo()
    Range("A1:A100").ClearContents
    Range("A1:A100").ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: OP is not require to clear whole Range, required to clear content only for empty cells in range "A1:A100"